# how to parse xref tag in xslt

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt

i am using this xml

```
<body>
<p>The results are used to optimize the design in the next product cycle through the V.</p>
<p> This feedback is represented by arrows between the left and right side of the V<xref ref-type="fig" rid="F1">Figure 1</xref>Physical test benches are often comprised of customized static.</p>
</body>
```

and this as xslt

```
<xsl:for-each select="body/">
 <xsl:value-of select="text()">
 </xsl:for-each>
```

And it is giving output as

> The results are used to optimize the design in the next product cycle through the V.This feedback is represented by arrows between the left and right side of the V.

It is not reading string after xref tag. But i want to parse it and want the following as output.

> The results are used to optimize the design in the next product cycle through the V.This feedback is represented by arrows between the left and right side of the V. Physical test benches are often comprised of customized static.

What changes should i make to Xslt so that it can pass this tag also ?

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"/>

  <xsl:template match="book-part">
    <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>
        <xsl:for-each select="book-meta">
          <p>
            <b>
              <xsl:value-of select="book-title-group/book-title"/>
            </b>
          </p>
        </xsl:for-each>


        <xsl:for-each select="book-part-meta">
          <p>
            <b>
              <xsl:value-of select="title-group/title"/>
            </b>
          </p>

        </xsl:for-each>

        <xsl:for-each select="body/sec/p">
          <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
       </xsl:for-each>

      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is my xml.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<book-part book-part-type="chapter" book-part-number="1" id="PT-161_ch_1">
<book-meta>
<book-title-group>
<book-title>Software&#x002d;Hardware Integration in Automotive Product Development</book-title>
</book-title-group>
</book-meta>
<body>
<sec id="ch1.1">
<title>INTRODUCTION</title>
<p>The trends of increased functionality, improved performance, reduced size and increased complexity continue to evolve in the automotive electronics market. New system architectures are providing the performance and memory capability necessary to keep up with the hardware performance and software growth required by the automotive market trends. All of this technology growth implies a higher product cost and increased engineering effort required to develop these new products.</p>
 <p>IVV is that portion of the complete product or system life&#x002d;cycle phase captured in the right&#x002d;hand side &#x0028;RHS&#x0029; of the V&#x002d;diagram model &#x0028;see <xref ref-type="fig" rid="F96">Fig. 1</xref>&#x0029;. This RHS portion is sometimes called the &#x201C;build, test, and deliver phase &#x005B;<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="R65">1</xref>&#x005D;.&#x201D; The model&#x2019;s left&#x002d;hand side is where the architectural design is functionally partitioned and decomposed into manageable subsystems and components. At the lowest levels of decomposition&#x002d;i.e., the bottom of the &#x201C;V&#x201D;&#x002d;the resulting subsystems are ready to be recomposed into an integrated whole. This integration phase is where verification, validation, and test of all the hardware and software occur.</p>

</sec>
</body>
</book-part>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write another template to capture the content of the `xref` element:

```
<xsl:template match="xref">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

Having said this, this depends on aspects of your stylesheet that you do *not* show. Here is a full stylesheet that also outputs text inside of `xref`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/body">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p|xref">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You should avoid using `xsl:for-each` where possible. Using several templates and `apply-templates` is the more in-the-spirit-of-XSLT way of doing it.

**EDIT**: I added a stylesheet that works with your updated input and is similar to your attempted XSLT solution.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/book-part">
  <html>
     <head></head>
     <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="book-meta">
 <p>
    <b>
       <xsl:value-of select="book-title-group/book-title"/>
    </b>
 </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="body|sec|p">
 <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()[parent::p]">
 <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()[parent::xref]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to the following input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<book-part book-part-type="chapter" book-part-number="1" id="PT-161_ch_1">
 <book-meta>
  <book-title-group>
   <book-title>Software and Hardware Integration in Automotive Product Development</book-title>
  </book-title-group>
 </book-meta>
 <body>
  <sec id="ch1.1">
   <title>INTRODUCTION</title>
    <p>The trends of increased functionality, improved performance, reduced size and increased complexity continue to evolve in the automotive electronics market.</p>
    <p> First part of the sentence <xref ref-type="fig" rid="F96">Fig. 1</xref>second part of the sentence.</p>
  </sec>
 </body>
</book-part>
```

You get the following output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
  <p><b>Software and Hardware Integration in Automotive Product Development</b></p>INTRODUCTIONThe trends of increased functionality, improved performance, reduced size and increased complexity continue to evolve in the
  automotive electronics market. First part of the sentence second part of the sentence.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i am not getting where to write it. Because <xsl:template match> can't be a child of <xsl:for-each select> and if i create another template then it is giving old result again. It is not parsing <xref> tag.

Comment: That's right. Either use my suggested stylesheet or add your entire stylesheet to the post by editing it. Only then I will be able to tell you what to do exactly.

Comment: i have added my xslt. now please explain me where to edit in order to parse <xref> tag .

Comment: ... together with an XML input sample that shows all the elements that you process in your stylesheet :-) thanks!

Comment: Hi, i have added my xml file too. now will you please help me ?